# Multiple "Placed from IP" addresses in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

In Magento when viewing an order in the admin panel you see a field at the top that says "Placed from IP".  Sometimes I see multiple IP addresses, like this:

```
Placed from IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy, zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz)
```

Is this normal?  What does it mean when there are multiples?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, it means that it was placed from behind a proxy. If you do an IP lookup on both of the IP addresses it should clarify what is happening.